# git checkout not creating local branch and tracking remote by default

Tags: git

I'm cloning a website repo. The remote host is fairly limited; I can't make a fork of the repo.

When I clone the repo, the origin is set as the remote host, `mysite@mysite.acquia.com`. When I do `git checkout {branch name}`, the new local branch is automatically tracking the remote

Because I don't want to put a bunch of development branches on the remote repo, I removed the origin with `git remote rm origin`. Then I made a new remote called `origin` based on a `bare` repo on our internal shared drive: `git remote add origin file:///h/path-to-repo`. (This remote already has my development branches).

Then, because I will eventually want to push my development branches to the common remote repo, I added back the original origin, this time calling it `acquia`: `git remote add acquia mysite@mysite.acquia.com`.

So now my remotes look like this:

```
$ git remote -vv
acquia mysite@mysite.acquia.com
origin file:///h/path-to-repo
```

However, when I checkout a branch from either remote, the default behavior is no longer to create a new local branch of the same name that is tracking the remote. Instead, I'm in a headless state:

```
$ git checkout origin/2017-04-11_social-media-footer
Note: checking out 'origin/2017-04-11_social-media-footer'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 8fe45a25... Pinned social media view at 3 columns

$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at origin/2017-04-11_social-media-footer)
  Sprint-04282017
  remotes/acquia/2017-03-30_feature-a
  remotes/acquia/2017-03-31_feature-b
  ... 
  remotes/acquia/2017-04-11_social-media-footer
  ...
```

Of course, I can create a new local branch matching the name of the remote branch, and set it to track the remote branch, but I'm used to that happening automatically. That's what does happen, before I change the remotes.

How do I get my git repo to automatically branch and track the remote when I check out a remote branch?

I'm using git version 2.12.0.windows.1 on git-bash on windows 7.

**EDIT** I did a regular clone, without changing the remotes, to test what I feel is expected behavior

```
$ git clone mysite@mysite.acquia.com
Cloning into 'mysite'...
remote: Counting objects: 19980, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16606/16606), done.
remote: Total 19980 (delta 6440), reused 15091 (delta 2786)
Receiving objects: 100% (19980/19980), 49.65 MiB | 176.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6440/6440), done.
Checking out files: 100% (12066/12066), done.

$ cd mysite; git branch
* master

$ git checkout 2017-04-05_memcache
Checking out files: 100% (210/210), done.
Switched to a new branch '2017-04-05_memcache'
Branch 2017-04-05_memcache set up to track remote branch 2017-04-05_memcache from origin.

$ git branch
* 2017-04-05_memcache
  master

# what is this branch tracking?
$ git  rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}
origin/2017-04-05_memcache
```

So by default, when I clone a remote repo, checking out a branch on the remote creates a local branch of the same name, and sets it up to track the remote. This is the behavior I'm used to from all my workplaces and at home. What have I done here to change this default behavior?

Comment: In the example that works, you're checking out a remote branch omitting the `remote/` prefix, such as `origin/`. If you haven't already gotten a local branch when you do this, and there is a remote branch matching, it is inferred that you want to create a local branch tracking the remote branch. This is your last example. If, on the other hand, you checkout the remote branch by its full name, you end up in detached head mode.  What happens if you try `git checkout 2017-04-11_social-media-footer` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why it doesn't work: the shortcut has too many alternatives

The basic problem boils down to this one sentence in [the `git checkout` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

> If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in ***exactly one*** remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

(emphasis mine).

Suppose you have only one remote, and you enter the command:

```
git checkout 2017-04-05_memcache
```

Git sees that there is no `2017-04-05_memcache` yet, checks through all your remotes, finds the single matching `origin/2017-04-05_memcache`, and does the quoted thing.

Suppose now you have *two* remotes, `origin` and `acquia`, and enter the same command.  If only *one* remote has `origin/2017-04-05_memcache` or `acquia/2017-04-05_memcache`, it again all just works.  But if *both* have their corresponding remote-tracking branches, Git does not know *which one to use*.  It throws up its metaphorical hands and makes you type in a longer command.

#### The long way and another, different, shortcut

Personally, I would probably just type in `git checkout -b 2017-04-05_memcache <remote>/2017-04-05_memcache`.  However, a bit further down in that same documentation, we see:

> --track
>
>   When creating a new branch, set up "upstream" configuration. See "--track" in
>   [git-branch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html)
>   for details.
>
>   If no
>   `-b`
>   option is given, the name of the new branch will be derived from the remote-tracking branch, by looking at the local part of the refspec configured for the corresponding remote, and then stripping the initial part up to the "*". This would tell us to use "hack" as the local branch when branching off of "origin/hack" (or "remotes/origin/hack", or even "refs/remotes/origin/hack"). If the given name has no slash, or the above guessing results in an empty name, the guessing is aborted. You can explicitly give a name with
>   `-b`
>   in such a case.

Hence, you can type in:

```
git checkout -t origin/2017-04-11_social-media-footer
```

rather than:

```
git checkout -b 2017-04-05_memcache origin/2017-04-05_memcache
```

and get the same effect: you specify your remote-tracking branch name (which lets you pick *which remote* you want) *and* the `-t` or `--track` option, and Git guesses at the *local* branch name to create, instead of the usual method of specfying the local name and letting Git guess which of your remote-tracking branches you meant.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -t origin/branchname` should to the trick.

From the manual:

```
       -t, --track
           When creating a new branch, set up "upstream" configuration. See "--track" in git-
           branch(1) for details.
```

Comment: That does indeed work as advertised, but how to I change the default behavior of git to use that? How did I jack it up in the first place?

Comment: Using checkout without `-t` makes git simply resolve the `origin/branchname` as a commit. When you want to locally create a new branch you will always have to pass either `-t` or `-b`

Comment: My workflow has been different; I just test a fresh clone where I didn't change the remotes. When I checked out a remote branch, I didn't have to pass `-t` or `-b` to get a new local branch. See my edits.

Comment: But you checked out the remote branch by omitting the remote prefix, such as `origin/`, this makes a difference.